# get corresponding column value from another dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, compare, match, multiple-columns

Below are two dataframes that I am comparing. I would like to get the corresponding column value under column `Usage` in `df2` when I am able to match the column `Item`. Appreciate help.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Number':[1.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,8.0,12.0,32.0,58.0,72.0] , 'Item': ['Phone', 'Watch', 'Pen', 'Pencil', 'Pencil', 'toolkit', 'box', 'fork', 'toy']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Number':[3.0, 4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 15.0, 32.0, 54.0, 58.0, 72.0], 'Item':['Watch', 'Pen', 'Pencil', 'Eraser', 'bottle', 'box', 'toolkit', 'fork', 'Phone'], 'Usage':['Time', 'Writing', 'Writing', 'Cleaning', 'Water', 'storage', 'Utility', 'Eat', 'Communication']})

df1
   Number     Item
0     1.0    Phone
1     3.0    Watch 
2     4.0      Pen
3     5.0   Pencil
4     8.0   Pencil   
5    12.0  toolkit
6    32.0      box
7    58.0     fork
8    72.0      toy

df2
   Number     Item          Usage
0     3.0    Watch           Time
1     4.0      Pen        Writing
2     8.0   Pencil        Writing
3    12.0   Eraser       Cleaning
4    15.0   bottle          Water
5    32.0      box        storage
6    54.0  toolkit        Utility
7    58.0     fork            Eat
8    72.0    Phone  Communication
```

Code used for matching is below. It says 'MatchedBoth' even when only the number has matched. This needs to be fixed.

```
import numpy as np
df3 = df1.copy()
df3['Matching'] = np.nan
df3.loc[(df3.Number.isin(df2.Number)) & (df3.Item.isin(df2.Item)), 'Matching'] = 'MatchedBoth'
df3.loc[(df3.Number.isin(df2.Number)) & (~df3.Item.isin(df2.Item)),'Matching'] = 'Matched Number Only'
df3.Matching.fillna('No Match', inplace=True)
```

In the same code is there any possibility to embed a return value that can fetch the `Usage` column value from `df2` ,corresponding per matched row. It may be a case where there are multiple rows that could match and hence we might need to get the corresponding `Usage` column values into a list or something like that in the final output.

Note: In my actual dataframe I have several columns apart from these and hence if I use merge it results in a huge dataframe. I'd just like to create a new column with the list of corresponding matched values found in the `Usage` column in df2.

Output should look something like below.

```
df3
   Number     Item             Matching    Usage
0     1.0    Phone             No Match      NaN
1     3.0    Watch          MatchedBoth     Time
2     4.0      Pen          MatchedBoth  Writing
3     5.0   Pencil             No Match      NaN
4     8.0   Pencil          MatchedBoth  Writing 
5    12.0  toolkit  Matched Number Only  Utility
6    32.0      box          MatchedBoth  storage
7    58.0     fork          MatchedBoth      Eat
8    72.0      toy  Matched Number Only     Play
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Number', how='left')
df3['Matching'] = np.where(df3.Productdetailed == df3.Item, 'Matched', 'No Match')
df3.drop('Productdetailed', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

which will return the output you indicated in your question.

EDIT after clarification:

```
def find_match(row):
  if (row.Number in df2.Number.values) & (row.Item in df2.Item.values):
      return "MatchedBoth"
  elif ((row.Number in df2.Number.values) & ~(row.Item in df2.Item.values)):
      return "Matched Number Only"
  else:
      return "No Match"

df3['Matching'] = df3.apply(find_match, axis=1)
df3['Usage'] = df3.Item.map(df2.set_index('Item').Usage)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but in my code I am doing multi level comparisons. I would like to compare both Item and Number column and tell MatchedBoth in the Matching column. If only the number matches then I would like to say MatchedNumberOnly. At the same time fetch the corresponding value in Usage column. There are multiple match criteria involved. Also, in my orginal dataset if I merge, I will get multiple other unwanted columns making the resultant dataframe very huge.

Comment: Sorry but your example is a bit unclear, you make `df3 = df1.copy() and then use conditionals like `(df3.Item.isin(df2.Item)` but df3 does not have an `Item` column. Is the `Productdetailed` column in `df1` suppose to be named `Item`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I have edited it now. You are correct. I am comparing the Item and Number columns with two conditions. But what I need is as I compare and I kno the columns match I will need to update a new column called Matching with the corresponding status and another column should collect the value or values in the usage column and put it in a new column in the df3 dataframe. In my actual dataset I have multiple columns and so a merge option could complicate stuff. My bad that I didnt mention that in the question. i shall edit the question now

Comment: Please advice if something like .map() or .apply() could be used.

Comment: Sorry, I am still unable to follow your code example or your explanation. The definition of `df1` still has the column incorrectly defined as `Productdescription` and the outcome you say you wish to have has no instances of `'Matched Number Only'`. It would be helpful if you can define the example DataFrames as you actually have them, and then provide an example output that matches what you expect. If I understand what you are trying to do then I would try using `df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['Number', 'Item'], how='outer')` and then do the matching based on duplicates of `Item` or `Number`

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I am finding it hard to explain it in here. I have edited the question again. I have brought in the output in a better way so you can understand. I hope.

Comment: First thing must be to compare the both Number and Item columns. based on the outcome the value found in the Usage column must be appended. This is what I actually need.

Comment: Your example is still unclear and the outcome you desire doesn't match what you are providing in your example. In your outcome you show the last row of the DataFrame having a `Usage = 'Play'` but no where in your `df2` DataFrame does any `Item` have a `Usage = 'Play'`.  I've edited the answer again, and hopefully it is similar to what you would like, otherwise good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your patience. This helps!.